# Is it possible to set long value for seekbar.setmax()?

Tags: android

I want to set long value for seekbar.setmax,is it possible?

If no, what are other alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Um, considering that there are no Android devices with over `Integer.MAX_VALUE` pixels in the horizontal direction, what use is there in having a `long` for `setMax()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Is the maximal range of a progress really pixel dependent? Because low resolutions don't support Integer.MAX_VALUE pixels either.

Comment: I have put seekbar to change date value. Seekbar has start and end date and user can slide in between these 2 values. Difference can be second,minute,hour,day,month or even year. So when the difference is more than 2 or 3 months. It doesn't work because of it exceed the value of max integer supported by android.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the need to be second-precise when sliding between years (I think it would be crucial to hit the second you want when there are more than just 2000 possible positions - having `Integer.MAX_VALUES` options would be really hard in my opinion) you could scale the precision of the choice to a reasonable measure.

That would give you the option to use the value of the seekbar as, say, days. You might declare a Calendar and set it to the start date, then adding the days to the calendar using Calendar's `add()` methods.
You would just have to calculate the difference between start and end, then you could decide what field of the Calendar is changed by changing the seekbars progress.

Answer (score 0):

Because LongClick is conflicting with EventMotion(ACTION_MOVE) of SeekBar, we can define an interface of LongClick to reslove the problem.

// 支持长按事件垂直摆放的 SeekBar

// VerticalSeekBar have longclick behavior

```
public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    private Drawable mThumb;
    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener mOnSeekBarChangeListener;
    private LongClickListener longClickListener;
    private long downTime;
    private boolean hasLongTouch = false;//是否已经执行长按操作
    private boolean possibleLongTouch = true;//可能是长按
    private float lastY;
    private float lastX;


    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 1 && !hasLongTouch) {
                hasLongTouch = true;
                if (longClickListener != null) longClickListener.onLongClick();
            }
        }
    };


    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener l) {
        mOnSeekBarChangeListener = l;
    }

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.rotate(-90);
        c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    void onProgressRefresh(float scale, boolean fromUser) {
        Drawable thumb = mThumb;
        if (thumb != null) {
            setThumbPos(getHeight(), thumb, scale, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            invalidate();
        }
        if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
            mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, getProgress(), fromUser);
        }
    }

    private void setThumbPos(int w, Drawable thumb, float scale, int gap) {
        int available = w - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

        int thumbWidth = thumb.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int thumbHeight = thumb.getIntrinsicHeight();

        int thumbPos = (int) (scale * available + 0.5f);


        int topBound, bottomBound;
        if (gap == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            Rect oldBounds = thumb.getBounds();
            topBound = oldBounds.top;
            bottomBound = oldBounds.bottom;
        } else {
            topBound = gap;
            bottomBound = gap + thumbHeight;
        }
        thumb.setBounds(thumbPos, topBound, thumbPos + thumbWidth, bottomBound);
    }

    public void setThumb(Drawable thumb) {
        mThumb = thumb;
        super.setThumb(thumb);
    }

    void onStartTrackingTouch() {
        if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
            mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);
        }
    }

    void onStopTrackingTouch() {
        if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
            mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
        }
    }

    private void attemptClaimDrag() {
        if (getParent() != null) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float y = event.getY();
        float x = event.getX();

        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                setPressed(true);
                onStartTrackingTouch();
                hasLongTouch = false;// 是否已经执行过长按事件
                possibleLongTouch = true;//是否可能为长按模式
                lastY = y;
                lastX = x;
                downTime = System.currentTimeMillis();//记录按下的时间
                if (!handler.hasMessages(1)) {//如果消息队列中已有消息 则不在重新发送
                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 800);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                attemptClaimDrag();
                setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));

                onStopTrackingTouch();
                //移动时如果x|y滑动了一段距离 则不可能为长按事件 即将 possibleLongTouch置为false
                if (lastX != 0 && lastY != 0 && (Math.abs(y - lastY) > 5 || Math.abs(x - lastX) > 5)) {
                    possibleLongTouch = false;
                    handler.removeMessages(1);

                }
                lastY = y;
                lastX = x;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                onStopTrackingTouch();
                setPressed(false);
                lastX = 0;
                lastY = 0;
                handler.removeMessages(1);
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - downTime > 800 && possibleLongTouch) {
                    if (!hasLongTouch) {//如果已经执行过长按操作  则不需要再次执行
                        hasLongTouch = true;
                        if (longClickListener != null) {
                            longClickListener.onLongClick();
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                onStopTrackingTouch();
                setPressed(false);
                handler.removeMessages(1);
                lastX = 0;
                lastY = 0;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // 定义长按接口
    // define longclick interface
    public interface LongClickListener {
        void onLongClick();
    }

    public void setLongClickListener(LongClickListener longClickListener) {
        this.longClickListener = longClickListener;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: OK, This is a CustomView，I define the callback to reslove event of longclick. The Main code are onTouchEvent（），the method  analyse the touch (longclick or move),it works in my project.  How to Use? I will show:

Comment: sb_volume.setLongClickListener(new VerticalSeekBar.LongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLongClick() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"LongClick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                
            }
        });